# How to get channels configured in Mythtv?

Tags: 16.04, mythtv

I can scan channels by `dvbv5-scan -C FI` from initial files /usr/share/dvb/dvb-t/fi-Tampere (UHF) and /usr/share/dvb/dvb-t/fi-DNA-Vesilahti (VHF). Can I use that information to get MyhthTV channels set?

If I scan by mythtv-setup, I do not get the channels from the latter transmitter and from the former I get many (like 38) conflicting channels. It is odd that before installing the VHF antenna I managed to get the UHF channels by mythtv-setup without such conflicts; the signal was measured better by the technician after he renewed the wires and the splitter.

I have mythtv 0.28, Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. The tuner is Hauppauge WinTV dualHD TV tuner stick (which requires custom kernel and PPA currently).

Comment: I managed to get channels configured by adding more channel frequencies manually and re-scanning them. But now the frontend refuses to play livetv.

Comment: Someone else had this problem with conflicting channels https://gist.github.com/bollinger/a0b97712bb4967e5d3ce2563ef6779e5